# A class that can be used as a transform view

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Assume that I have a class that does some work, and eventually constructs a view over some containers and offers that for iteration. Simplified example:

```
class BuildAView
{
     BuildAView(std::array<float, 5> &in)
        : mIn{in}
    {
        // Do something non-trivial, so that I need a class instead of just a function
        // getView
    }

    auto getView()
    {
       return mIn | std::views::transform([](float x){return doSomething(x);});
    }
    
private:
     std::array<float, 5> &mIn;

};
```

This works, but the usage is `for (auto && x : buildAView.getView())`.

The syntax I'd like is `for (auto && x : buildAView)`, i.e. the class itself acts as a range. However, the trivial attempt doesn't work:

```
class BuildAView
{
    ...
    // Everything else as above, but instead of getView, directly begin() and end()
    auto begin()
    {
       // Does not work, returns a temporary that ends up dangling...
       return (mIn | std::views::transform([](float x){return doSomething(x);})).begin();
    }
    auto end()
    {
       // Does not work, returns a temporary that ends up dangling...
       return (mIn | std::views::transform([](float x){return doSomething(x);})).end();
    }
    ...
};
```

but that returns dangling temporaries, as GCC kindly informs me. In addition, the begin and end pointers are of a different type, because the lambda's are formally different type, although this I can fix by replacing the lambda with an appropriate free function.

What I've tried:

- building the view in the constructor so I can store it. I can make that work sometimes, but the problem is that coughing up the type of the view for the member variable ends up being very convoluted, sometimes impossible (it's easy to accidentally use unnamed or unnameable types), and as far as I know can't be deduced
- using free begin() and end() does not seem to help, the dangling happens just the same, since there's still no obvious place to store the view

The question: can I build a type that acts like a range, but actually use std::views::transform etc to build said rangem like in the example? Or maybe I'm thinking of this completely wrong, and there's some trivial way to get the same end result?

Comment: Basically because I want to construct `BuildAView` in one place, and use it at another, and at the use site I'd like to not need to know if it's a container or some view of it.

So the objection to both of your suggestions is that I have to separately pass `in`

Comment: what speaks against storing the result of `mIn | std::views::transform([](float x){return doSomething(x);});` as member and let `begin` and `end` return the `begin` and `end` of that memer?

Comment: "coughing up the type of the view for the member variable ends up being very convoluted, sometimes impossible [...] and as far as I know can't be deduced"  its not impossible, it can be decuded. it is `decltype(mIn | std::views::transform([](float x){return doSomething(x);});)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Been there, done that. In your example, the type of the lambda will be different when declaring the member variable than by the time you're assigning it in the constructor. Similar complications abound.

Comment: "the type of the lambda will be different when declaring the member variable than by the time you're assigning it in the constructor. " thats an issue of code I kept short to be able to post it in a comment, but its not something that cannot be overcome

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I know, it can be worked around. But when I keep trying get the type, there seems to be always a new complication. The last one that I didn't figure out how to pass was when the input array is non-const and has an alignment requirement, as the align is apparently not picked up by `decltype`, and being non-const means that I can't construct a temporary reference. My point being that getting the build type does not seem to be a general / sustainable way to do this.

Comment: Not to mention that that way I have to write the transform twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a class member, you can make the range a static variable of the `begin` function implement the `end` function in terms of `begin`:

```
auto begin() {
    static auto res = getView();
    return res.begin();
}
auto end() {
    return std::next(begin(), mIn.size());
}
```

note however, that this leads to inefficient code, when your range is not a random access range and does not work, if the range of `getView` has a different length than `mIn`.

Comment: Actually, in my use case I'd anyway want the length of the view to be a compile time constant that I can build without even knowing the view, so I'm happy with the length limitation. I'll wait for a while to see if anyone has more answers, before accepting yours. Thanks!

Comment: alright, I am interested to see other approaches too

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with writing the transformation as a separate function, you could write a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) for the type of the view result. It still needs `decltype` though:

```
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int doSomething(float x) { return x; }

template<std::ranges::range Range>
inline auto transformation(const Range& container) {
    return std::move(container | std::views::transform([](float x) { return doSomething(x); }));
}

template<std::ranges::range Range, typename ResultRange>
struct BuildAView {
    BuildAView(const Range& mIn) : range(transformation(mIn)) {
    }

    auto begin() { return range.begin(); }
    auto end() { return range.end(); }
    ResultRange range;
};

// deduction guide to determine ResultRange from input range
template<std::ranges::range Range>
BuildAView(Range& cont) -> BuildAView<Range, decltype(transformation(cont))>;


int main() {
    std::array<float, 5> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    BuildAView buildAView(arr);
    for (auto&& x: buildAView) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

**Note** however that the `range` member needs to be initialized in the initializer list, as these range types don't have a default constructor.

The deduction guide can also be specific, in case you do not want to template `BuildAView` over the range used.

```
BuildAView(std::array<float, 5>& cont) -> BuildAView<decltype(transformation(cont))>;
```

Comment: This might also be feasible. The decltype is much better  here,  since it's not necessary to list the whole view expression inside it.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to deduce the type of the instance whose `begin` and `end` you want to call. Perhaps your example is too simplified and does not show the difficulty you have with deducing the type. However, this works:

```
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

float doSomething(float x){ return x * 2;}

template <typename T>
struct BuildAView
{
    BuildAView(const T& t) : t{t} {}
    auto begin() { return t.begin(); }
    auto end() { return t.end(); }
    T t;
};


auto make_BuildAView(const std::array<float,5>& mIn) {
    return mIn | std::views::transform([](float x){return doSomething(x);});
}

int main() {
    std::array<float,5> arr{1,2,3,4,5};
    BuildAView buildAView = make_BuildAView(arr);
    for (auto && x : buildAView) { std::cout << x << " ";}
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oTnvdEKPT)

Plain CTAD would work too, but I suppose you want to wrap the expression `mIn | std::views::transform([](float x){return doSomething(x);});` somewhere so the user can simply construct the `BuildAView` without bothering with the details of the transformation.